# With using lmfit module in python, how to call the parameters in the model?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, lmfit

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from lmfit import minimize, Parameters, Parameter, report_fit


# create data to be fitted


x = np.linspace(0, 15, 301)

data = (5. * np.sin(2 * x - 0.1) * np.exp(-x*x*0.025) +

np.random.normal(size=len(x), scale=0.2) )

# define objective function: returns the array to be minimized


def fcn2min(params, x, data):

    """ model decaying sine wave, subtract data"""
    amp = params['amp'].value
    shift = params['shift'].value
    omega = params['omega'].value
    decay = params['decay'].value
    model = amp * np.sin(x * omega + shift) * np.exp(-x*x*decay)


    return model - data


# create a set of Parameters

params = Parameters()

params.add('amp',   value= 10,  min=0)

params.add('decay', value= 0.1)

params.add('shift', value= 0.0, min=-np.pi/2., max=np.pi/2)

params.add('omega', value= 5.0)


# do fit, here with leastsq model

result = minimize(fcn2min, params, args=(x, data))


# calculate final result

final = data + result.residual


# try to plot results
plt.plot(x,data,'k+')

plt.plot(x,final,'r')

plt.show()
```

In this code, I want to call the parameters like 'amp', 'shift' in the python.
Print(amp).. kinds of things
How to call these parameters in the python after fitting?
When I use print(amp), the error message is shown; name 'amp' is not defined. How to print these fitted parameters using print function? (etc. print(amp))

Comment: It is kind of hard to understand what you really want or asking for? What works in your code, and what doesn't work?

Comment: If you run the code, you can find the code is working well. However, I want to call the fitted parameters like 'amp', and 'decay'. When I use print(amp), the error message is shown; name 'amp' is not defined.           How to print these parameters using print function? (etc. print(amp))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely trying to print that data outside of the function. The `amp`, `shift`, `omega` and `decay` variables are in `fc2min`'s local scope and are therefore only accessible inside the function. Your data analysis skills seem to far outmatch your Python know-how, so I added some helpful tips inside this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters, Parameter, report_fit

# create data to be fitted
x = np.linspace(0, 15, 301)
data = (5. * np.sin(2 * x - 0.1) * np.exp(-x*x*0.025) +
np.random.normal(size=len(x), scale=0.2) )

# define objective function: returns the array to be minimized
def fcn2min(params, x, data):

    """ model decaying sine wave, subtract data"""
    amp = params['amp'].value
    shift = params['shift'].value
    omega = params['omega'].value
    decay = params['decay'].value
    model = amp * np.sin(x * omega + shift) * np.exp(-x*x*decay)

    # tell Python we're modifying the model_data list
    # that was declared outside of this function
    global model_data

    # store the model data produced by this function call
    # add any data you want to display later to this "dictionary"
    model_data += [{
        "amp": amp,
        "shift": shift,
        "omega": omega,
        "decay": decay
    }]

    return model - data


# create a set of Parameters
params = Parameters()
params.add('amp',   value= 10,  min=0)
params.add('decay', value= 0.1)
params.add('shift', value= 0.0, min=-np.pi/2., max=np.pi/2)
params.add('omega', value= 5.0)

# declare an empty list to hold the model data
model_data = []

# do fit, here with leastsq model
result = minimize(fcn2min, params, args=(x, data))

# print each item in the model data list
for datum in model_data:
    for key in datum:

        #the 5 in %.5f controls the precision of the floating point value
        print("%s: %.5f  ") % (key, datum[key]),
    print


# calculate final result
final = data + result.residual

# try to plot results
plt.plot(x,data,'k+')
plt.plot(x,final,'r')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I used your code, then the eroor is occured; unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'Nonetype' and 'tuple'. How can I treat it?

Comment: I edit your code print(("%s: %.5f  ") % (key, datum[key])), and it works.

Comment: Then, How to get only the 'amp' value outside the function?? Only the datum is used for outside the function in your code.

Comment: `for datum in model_data:`    `print(datum["amp"])`   Sorry, didn't know you were using Python 3

Comment: Then, could I print the final fitted parameter, not whole parameters?

Comment: I don't know what that means. Can you explain?

Comment: When you use --> for datum in model_data: print(datum["amp"]), you can find many numbers of amp are shown. I want to find the last amp number.

Comment: `model_data[-1]` will give you the full last entry, `model_data[-1]["amp"]` will give you the last `amp` value.

Comment: I use model_data[-1]["amp"], the last amp values are duplicated in many lines. How to fix it?

Comment: Remove the `for` loop(s)

Comment: Finally, it works very well. Thanks for your kind help.